# Unable to use page objects in my spec file in protractor

Tags: protractor, webstorm

//This is my AngularPage.cs page object file

```
 var AngularPage= function()
 {
 var nameInput= element(by.model('yourName'));
 var greeting = element(by.binding('yourName'));

 this.get=function()
 {
    browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');
 };
 this.setName= function(name)
 {
    nameInput.sendKeys(name);

 };

 this.getGreeting= function()
 {
    return greeting.getText();`
 };
};
module.exports = new AngularPage();
```

//This is my AngularHome_spec.js file

```
var angularPage = require('./AngularPage.js');
describe('angularjs homepage',function()
{
    var angular_page;

    beforeEach(function()
    {
        angular_page= new AngularPage();
    });

    it('greetings for new user', function()
        {
           // var angular_page= new AngularPage();
            angular_page.get();
            angular_page.setName('Rahul');
            expect(angular_page.getGreeting()).toEqual('Hello Rahul!');
        }
    );

 }

 );
```

//I am unable to use page objects in my spec file as it is throwing an error 
   :AngularPage is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, object has been created twice. First time on page "AngularPage.js" and second time on spec "AngularHome_spec.js" level.

1. Do following on page "AngularHome_spec.js"

   ```
    module.exports = AngularPage;
   ```
2. Change the

   ```
    var AngularPage = require('./AngularPage.js');//Capital the 'A'
   ```

Comment: Thanks!!.. It Worked :)